# How to correctly type a generic React function component in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

In the following [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgAUcwBnAFVvoF44BvcuHGAATAFxwWMKMAB2AcwA05AJAA3FABsArknGTp8pQF8KVTnADiSGUmlomEVhzoAeANZJqzpAD44PfkERcQ8vTiU1TR09KVlFchNKNAgZSTgAUQ0kEGsYcWR0GAA6ADEAYRcHJ04-HgAKXhEFOHVtJCMASn8-fmUiGC0oGTgXYWBVH0bhIpgIAGVY%20TqOoy5eVp0jFwB6MYmKRPJk1PgrGztM7Nz84mLylzPbYHtmdk53T28fWpHQ738JIs5D4Gk0WlF2l0uD0VP1BsNRuNJiIZvMgctVusIVtdkiDhQgA) example I tried to generalise the function component `Element` into a `GenericElement` component but TypeScript complains about the syntax.

How to correctly type a generic react function component in TypeScript using the `React.FC` type definition approach?

```js
import React from 'react';

type PropsType = {
  id: string,
  value: string,
};

type GenericPropsType<keyType> = {
  id: keyType,
  value: string,
};

const Element: React.FC<PropsType> = ({ id, value }) => {
  return <div>{id.toString()}={value}</div>;
};

const GenericElement: React.FC<GenericPropsType<keyType>> = <keyType = string>({ id, value }) => {
  return <div>{id.toString()}={value}</div>;
};
```

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<GenericPropsType<any>>'.
Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: PropsWithChildren<GenericPropsType<any>>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
Cannot find name 'keyType'.
Property 'keyType' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.
Cannot find name 'id'.
Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
Cannot find name 'value'.
Cannot find name 'id'.
Cannot find name 'value'.
Identifier expected.
Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'>'}` or `&gt;`?
Expression expected.
Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?
JSX element 'keyType' has no corresponding closing tag.
'</' expected.
'Element' is declared but its value is never read.
```

Comment: You can't use `React.FC` in this case. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgHEkA7JKYNABRzAGcAVWkgA8AayTVBdAHxwAvHADe5OHGAATAFxxxkoQBpyASABuKADYBXJNt4x2zAOaGAvhXKZLzDMAjNGLGwcAKLmSCAsMGISUvRIAB4wLOq8SnAwEADK9sBOABQAlLY5TnAu8nB2Do7SecaKGvpwZlZILtpMrOxcPAJC0Xoy5AXKRkQwllD+wurAJtIN6gB0GdnVhS5yii3WLsIA9LPzFC7kQA

Comment: @AlekseyL. I believe you should write this an answer

Comment: @captain-yossarian There's _using the React.FC_ requirement in the question, that's why I'm not posting this as answer

Comment: @AlekseyL. I'm still a little confused. It seems as the problem is syntactical and is caused by using an arrow function instead of a function declaration. Is this a limitation of TypeScript? I also do not really understand the generic type parameter `<keyType extends { toString(): string } = string>`. Could you elaborate on `{ toString(): string }`?

Comment: Regarding `extends { toString(): string }` - it is generic type parameter constraint, so provided type must have `toString` method (you're doing `id.toString()` within the function). Regarding arrow function: if you use `React.FC` you can't leave generic type parameter "open" (provided by consumer)

Comment: Here's example defining component as an arrow function https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgHEkA7JKYNABRzAGcAVWkgA8AayTVBdAHxwAvHADe5OHGAATAFxxxkoQBoVcAG4oANgFck23jHbMA5oYC+FckgAekWHDQRmtowsbBwAomZIICzwCmISUvSeMCzqvEpwMBAAynbAjgAUAJQ2uY5wzvJwtvYO0vnkAJCKGvom5lbO2kys7Fw8AkJxejLkhfKywurAxtLN6gB0mTk1Rc5yiqaWSM7CAPRTM6RAA

Comment: @doberkofler one more thing - not sure why generics needed here. Why not define `id: string | number` for example?

Comment: @AlekseyL. You are absolutely correct. This is s contrived example only to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the explanation of @Aleksey L., I came to the following complete example that might be helpful to others:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

type GenericPropsType<keyType> = {
  id: keyType,
  value: string,
};

const GenericElement = <keyType extends string | number = string>({
  id,
  value = ''
}: GenericPropsType<keyType>): JSX.Element => {
  return (<div>{id}={value}</div>);
};

const UseGenericElement: React.FC = () => {
  return (<div><GenericElement id={4711} value="4711" /></div>);
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div><UseGenericElement /></div>,
  document.getElementById('root');
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it works using Higher-order function:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';

type GenericPropsType<T = any> = {
  id: T,
  value: string,
};

const HoC = <T,>(): FC<GenericPropsType<T>> => (props) => <div></div>

const WithString = HoC<string>() // React.FC<GenericPropsType<string>>
```

Drawback: you have function overhead only because of type

I don't believe my answer is helpful, because you should explicitly define generic type, or you need to pass an argument in order to infer it:

```js
const HoC = <T,>(a:T): FC<GenericPropsType<T>> => (props) => <div></div>

const WithString = HoC('a') // React.FC<GenericPropsType<string>>
```

Otherwise, I suggest you to use `@Aleksey L.`'s solution.